# How to SELECT N values ABOVE and BELOW from specific value

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

If I have a table:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jane | 10 |
| 2 | Stewe | 9 |
| 3 | John | 8 |
| 4 | Mike | 7 |
| 5 | Luke | 6 |
| 6 | Andrew | 5 |
| 7 | Carl | 4 |
| 8 | Sasha | 3 |
| 9 | Ariel | 2 |
| 10 | Carol | 1 |

I would like to SELECT 3 rows above and below WHERE Column B = someValue .

IF query SELECT * WHERE Column B = "Andrew" result should look like:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | John | 8 |
| 4 | Mike | 7 |
| 5 | Luke | 6 |
| 6 | Andrew | 5 |
| 7 | Carl | 4 |
| 8 | Sasha | 3 |
| 9 | Ariel | 2 |

I know how to select one row, but cant understand how to select such range.
Thanks for ideas!

Comment: Can you explain the result you expect? If you are filtering for 'Andrew' in column B shouldn't it only return row.6.

Comment: 3 rows above 'Andrew' and 3 rows below it. 
'Andrew' - would be like coordinate from where to go above and below

Comment: Use match() to find "andrew" then offset() as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `limit` and `offset` inside your `QUERY()`:

```
=QUERY(A1:C,"limit "&2+MIN(5,MATCH(D1,B:B,0))&" offset "&MAX(0,MATCH(D1,B:B,0)-5))
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, this was fun...

If 3 above or below are not available then blank... rolling data around is a different proposition.

Below the image is the list of formulae used.

[image]

So, per cell not including the data validation that is based on cells B2:B11

A14 and dragged down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$11,MATCH(B14,$B$2:$B$11,0)),"")
```

C14 and dragged down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$11,MATCH(B14,$B$2:$B$11,0)),"")
```

Cells B14 through B20:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(B$17,$B$2:$B$11,0)=3,NA(),INDEX($B$2:$B$11,MATCH(B$17,$B$2:$B$11,0)-3)),"")

=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(B$17,$B$2:$B$11,0)=2,NA(),INDEX($B$2:$B$11,MATCH(B$17,$B$2:$B$11,0)-2)),"")

=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(B$17,$B$2:$B$11,0)=1,NA(),INDEX($B$2:$B$11,MATCH(B$17,$B$2:$B$11,0)-1)),"")

=E2

=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$11,MATCH(B$17,$B$2:$B$11,0)+1),"")

=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$11,MATCH(B$17,$B$2:$B$11,0)+2),"")

=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$11,MATCH(B$17,$B$2:$B$11,0)+3),"")
```

Answer (score 1):

In Excel 365, you could try:

```
=INDEX(A:C,MAX(2,MATCH(D2,B:B,0)-3),0):INDEX(A:C,MIN(COUNTA(B:B),MATCH(D2,B:B,0)+3),0)
```

In Google sheets, on the other hand, the formula would be:

```
=INDEX(A:C,MAX(2,MATCH(D2,B:B,0)-3),0):INDEX(A:C,MIN(COUNTA(B:B),MATCH(D2,B:B,0)+3),0)
```

(spot the difference).

**Excel**

[image]

**Google Sheets**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should produce what you want in all cases:

`=IFERROR(FILTER(A2:C,B2:B<>"",ROW(A2:A)>=VLOOKUP("Andrew",{B2:B,ROW(B2:B)},2,FALSE)-3,ROW(A2:A)<=VLOOKUP("Andrew",{B2:B,ROW(B2:B)},2,FALSE)+3))`

Of course, you can replace the two instances of "Andrew" with a cell reference (one where you type a changeable name).

This just looks up the row in a curly-bracket array formed from the names and row numbers and uses `FILTER` to keep results to rows between +/-3 rows of where the target name is found. If you choose the first name (or any other name), you won't get an error; because even if the target name were on Row 1 and the formula goes looking for anything "greater than or equal to 1 minus 3, all rows will be greater than a negative number. Same on the high end. You just won't get a full seven names if there aren't at least three other rows prior to or after the target row.

Answer (score 0):

this not the best solution but it will work , you can use a helper column 'D' that contains the following formula `=if(countif(INDIRECT("B"&ROW()+3&":"&"B"&ROW()-3),"Andrew")>0,TRUE,FASLE)`
and u can query from here like this `SELECT * WHERE Column D = TRUE`